# ViewImports statements do not work sometimes

Tags: blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-6.0

Original title to question:
Getting error: Cannot convert System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

I am following a Blazor example in Visual Studio 2022, .NET 6 from a Pro ASP.NET Core 6 book. I am getting this error in a Blazor Razor component called `Product.razor`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SportsStore.Models.Product>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SportsStore.Pages.Admin.Product>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is the code for `Product.razor`:

```
@page "/admin/products"
@page "/admin"
@inherits OwningComponentBase<IStoreRepository>

<table class="table table-sm d-sm-table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th><th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (ProductData?.Count() > 0) {
            @foreach (Product p in ProductData){
                <tr>
                    <td>@p.ProductID</td>
                </tr>
            }
        };
    </tbody>
</table>

@code{
    public IStoreRepository Repository => Service;

    public IEnumerable<Product> ProductData { get; set; } 
        = Enumerable.Empty<Product>();

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        await UpdateData();
    }

    public async Task UpdateData() {
        ProductData = await Repository.Products.ToListAsync();
    }

    public string GetDetailsUrl(long id) => $"/admin/products/details/{id}";
    public string GetEditUrl(long id) => $"/admin/products/edit/{id}";
}
```

The error shows up in the `UpdateData` method:

[image]

Here is what the `IStoreRepository` interface looks like:

```
namespace SportsStore.Models 
{
    public interface IStoreRepository 
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }

        void SaveProduct(Product p);
        void CreateProduct(Product p);
        void DeleteProduct(Product p);
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation called `EFStoreRepository` using Entity Framework:

```
namespace SportsStore.Models 
{
    public class EFStoreRepository : IStoreRepository 
    {
        private StoreDbContext context;

        public EFStoreRepository(StoreDbContext ctx) 
        {
            context = ctx;
        }

        public IQueryable<Product> Products => context.Products;

        public void CreateProduct(Product p)
        {
            context.Add(p);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void DeleteProduct(Product p)
        {
            context.Remove(p);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void SaveProduct(Product p)
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `Product` class:

```
namespace SportsStore.Models 
{
    public class Product 
    {
        public long? ProductID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product name")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product description")]
        public string Description { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        [Range(0.01, double.MaxValue,
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive price")]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(8, 2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a category")]
        public string Category { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

There is also a `_ViewImports` file:

```
@namespace SportsStore.Pages
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages
@using SportsStore.Models
@using SportsStore.Infrastructure
@add TagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

I have pulled down the authors code and looked at it side by side.  I can't see any difference. I have no idea why I am getting this error.

Also I am not getting the correct properties for a Product since it cannot do the conversion correctly.

[image]

For instance, there should be ProductId, Name, Description, etc in the intellisense pop there.

**Update**

Well I found the problem but not the root cause.

It seems the using statement:

```
@using SportsStore.Models
```

is not being applied from the `_ViewImports` file.

This happened earlier in the book before and it really trips me up when it happens.

Has anyone else had this happen and been able to solve in their environment?

I had to fully qualify a `Product` in the statements to bring it into the `Product.razor` component.

Here is the updated component (I have not finished the tbody yet):

```
@page "/admin/products"
@page "/admin"
@inherits OwningComponentBase<IStoreRepository>

<table class="table table-sm d-sm-table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th><th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (ProductData?.Count() > 0) {
            @foreach (SportsStore.Models.Product p in ProductData){
                <tr>
                    <td>@p.ProductID</td>
                </tr>
            }
        };
    </tbody>
</table>

@code{
    public IStoreRepository Repository => Service;

    public IEnumerable<SportsStore.Models.Product> ProductData { get; set; } 
        = Enumerable.Empty<SportsStore.Models.Product>();

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        await UpdateData();
    }

    public async Task UpdateData() {
        ProductData = await Repository.Products.ToListAsync();
    }

    public string GetDetailsUrl(long id) => $"/admin/products/details/{id}";
    public string GetEditUrl(long id) => $"/admin/products/edit/{id}";
}
```

Comment: according to the error message, it seems you are mixing two classes with the same name: SportsStore.Models.Product and SportsStore.Pages.Admin.Product

Comment: The using statement:
@using SportsStore.Models;
in _ViewImports.cshtml should take care of it.
Even if I bring the using statement into the file it doesn't work.  The only thing that works is to fully qualify the Product everywhere in the Product.razor code.  It's like I it thinks I'm referring to the Product component instead of the product POCO.